# PassportJS, NestJS: canActivate method of AuthGuard('jwt')

Tags: passport.js, nestjs, passport-jwt, nestjs-passport, nestjs-jwt

Does anybody know where I can see the full code of canActivate method in AuthGuard('jwt')? I realized that canActivate method calls JwtStrategy validate method by using console.log() like this:

```js
// jwt.strategy.ts

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: true,
      secretOrKey: configService.get<string>('JWT_SECRET'),
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    try {
      const user = await this.usersService.getUserById(payload.id);
      // console.log is here
      console.log(user);
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

If I use the original canActivate method, console.log is called. I thought that JwtStrategy is a middleware so the validate method is called whenever there is a request. However, when I try to override canActivate method to add authorization, console.log in JwtStrategy validate method is not called:

```js
// jwt-auth.guard.ts

import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return ctx.getContext().req;
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    try {
      // Override: handle authorization
      // return true or false
      // Should JwtStrategy.validate(something) be called here?
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Then I tried to find the original code of AuthGuard('jwt') in order to understand its logic, but I was not able to. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, so this is gonna be a very *fun* deep dive into this. Buckle up.

[`Middleware`](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware) as express methods do still exist in NestJS; that said, this is not your normal middleware in the sense of Express middleware. As you'v mentioned `AuthGuard()#canActivate()` ends up calling the appropriate `PassportStrategy`. These strategies get [registered here](https://github.com/nestjs/passport/blob/master/lib/passport/passport.strategy.ts#L4) specifically on lines 40-41 where `passport.use()` gets called. This registers the passport strategy class's `validate` method to be used for `passport.verify()`. Most of the under the hood logic is very abstract and the context while reading it can be lost, so take your time and understand the concepts of classes, mixins (functions that return classes), and inheritance.

[Line 51 of AuthGuard](https://github.com/nestjs/passport/blob/master/lib/passport/passport.strategy.ts#L4) is where the `passportFn` originally gets created, and in this `passportFn` [passport.authenticate](https://github.com/nestjs/passport/blob/master/lib/auth.guard.ts#L98) gets called (which calls `passport.verify` under its hood) (reading through Passport's code is even more confusing, so I'll let you run that when you want).

If you want to add some extra logic to your `canActivate()` method you can end up calling `super.canActivate(context)` to call the original `canActivate()` method that ends up calling `passport.authenticate()` and thus `<Strategy>#validate`. That could look something like

```js
@Injectable()
export class CustomAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    // custom logic can go here
    const parentCanActivate = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean; // this is necessary due to possibly returning `boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean>
    // custom logic goes here too
    return parentCanActivate && customCondition;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Then, is there any way to get access to the return value of `<Strategy>#validate` outside of `super.canActivate(context)`? For example, the Strategy verifies the token and `validate` returns the valid payload containing userId. I want to find a user with the userId in the database, and handle authorization using the 'role' of the user which is saved in the database. Or, as my custom strategy already returns the full user entity, so I think being able to get the return value of `validate` would be enough.

Comment: Under the hood, `passport` will take whatever is returned by `validate` and set `req.user` to it, so if you Need `<Strategy#<validate>`'s return value, you can get it from `req.user`

Comment: Oh, that's great! To sum up, `super.canActivate(context)` returns a boolean whether the valid token is issued for the valid user, and after calling it `req.user` is set, so I can work with further logic using `req.user`. Thanks for your help!